# How to randomly shuffle a list

Tags: haskell, do-notation

I have random number generator

```
rand :: Int -> Int -> IO Int
rand low high = getStdRandom (randomR (low,high))
```

and a helper function to remove an element from a list

```
removeItem _ []                 = []
removeItem x (y:ys) | x == y    = removeItem x ys
                    | otherwise = y : removeItem x ys
```

I want to shuffle a given list by randomly picking an item from the list, removing it and adding it to the front of the list. I tried

```
shuffleList :: [a] -> IO [a]
shuffleList [] = []
shuffleList l = do 
                     y <- rand 0 (length l)
                     return( y:(shuffleList (removeItem  y l) ) )
```

But can't get it to work. I get

> ```
> hw05.hs:25:33: error:
>     * Couldn't match expected type `[Int]' with actual type `IO [Int]'
>     * In the second argument of `(:)', namely
>      ....
> ```

Any idea ?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to `res <- ...` the recursive IO call before using the result `return (y:res)`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Generally, with Haskell it works better to maximize the amount of *functional* code at the expense of non-functional (IO or randomness-related) code.

In your situation, your “maximum” functional component is not `removeItem` but rather a version of `shuffleList` that takes the input list and (as mentioned by Will Ness) a deterministic integer *position*. List function [splitAt :: Int -> [a] -> ([a], [a])](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:splitAt) can come handy here. Like this:

```
funcShuffleList :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
funcShuffleList _ [] = []
funcShuffleList pos ls =
    if (pos <=0) || (length(take (pos+1) ls) < (pos+1))
      then ls -- pos is zero or out of bounds, so leave list unchanged
      else let (left,right) = splitAt pos ls
           in  (head right) : (left ++ (tail right))
```

Testing:

```
 λ> 
 λ> funcShuffleList  4  [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
 [4,0,1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9]
 λ> 
 λ> funcShuffleList 5 "@ABCDEFGH"
 "E@ABCDFGH"
 λ>
```

Once you've got this, you can introduce randomness concerns in simpler fashion. And you do not need to involve IO explicitely, as any randomness-friendly monad will do:

```
shuffleList :: MonadRandom mr => [a] -> mr [a]
shuffleList [] = return []
shuffleList ls =
    do
       let maxPos = (length ls) - 1
       pos <- getRandomR (0, maxPos)
       return (funcShuffleList pos ls)
```

... IO being just one instance of [MonadRandom](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.1.3/docs/Control-Monad-Random-Class.html#t:MonadRandom).

You can run the code using the default IO-hosted random number generator:

```
main = do
    let inpList = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]::[Integer]

    putStrLn $ "inpList  = " ++ (show inpList)

    -- mr automatically instantiated to IO:
    outList1 <- shuffleList inpList
    putStrLn $ "outList1 = " ++ (show outList1)
    outList2 <- shuffleList outList1
    putStrLn $ "outList2 = " ++ (show outList2)
```

### Program output:

```
$ pickShuffle
inpList  = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
outList1 = [6,0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8]
outList2 = [8,6,0,1,2,3,4,5,7]
$ 
$ pickShuffle
inpList  = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
outList1 = [4,0,1,2,3,5,6,7,8]
outList2 = [2,4,0,1,3,5,6,7,8]
$
```

The output is not reproducible here, because the default generator is seeded by its launch time in nanoseconds.

If what you need is a full random permutation, you could have a look [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Random_shuffle) and [there - Knuth a.k.a. Fisher-Yates algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Comment: 1. the function that takes the input list and an integer position *is* `removeItem`. 2. the repeated calls as you show them result in non-uniform shuffling unlike the OP's code with `removeItem`. 3. measuring `length` is redundant, can be done with integer comparison, `length ls` should be known before the function call.

Comment: 4. the name "shuffleList" is confusing when only one card is shuffled

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I do agree that “shuffleList” is highly misleading, but it is the OP's nomenclature. Maybe use `moveElemToHead` and `moveRandomElemToHeadM` with M standing for monadic.

Comment: Regarding point 2, I am just putting a 2nd call to `shuffleList` in my example in order to show that calls can be sequenced easily; there is no higher claim. I think it is not clear from the text of the question whether or not the OP intends the `shuffleList` function to be a stepping stone towards a properly balanced whole list shuffling. I have just put a reference to Fisher-Yates at the end of my answer to cover for that risk.

Comment: I think their algo is already conforming to the first version in the haskellwiki link.

Answer (score 2):

Since `shuffleList :: [a] -> IO [a]`, we have `shuffleList (xs :: [a]) :: IO [a]`.

Obviously, we can't cons `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]` an `a` element onto an `IO [a]` value, but instead we want to cons it onto the list `[a]`, the computation of which that `IO [a]` value describes:

```
   do
         y <- rand 0 (length l)
         -- return ( y : (shuffleList (removeItem  y l) ) )
         shuffled  <-     shuffleList (removeItem  y l)
         return      y : shuffled
```

In `do` notation, values to the right of `<-` have types `M a`, `M b`, etc., for some monad `M` (here, `IO`), and values to the left of `<-`  have the corresponding types `a`, `b`, etc..

The `x :: a` in `x <- mx` gets bound to the pure value of type `a` produced / computed by the `M`-type computation which the value `mx :: M a` denotes, *when* that computation is actually performed, as a part of the combined computation represented by the whole `do` block, when *that* combined computation is performed as a whole.

And if e.g. the next line in that `do` block is `y <- foo x`, it means that a pure function `foo :: a -> M b` is applied to `x` and the result is calculated which is a value of type `M b`, denoting an `M`-type computation which then runs and produces / computes a pure value of type `b` to which the name `y` is then bound.

The essence of Monad is thus this slicing of *the pure* inside / between *the (potentially) impure*, it is these two timelines going on of the pure *calculations* and the potentially impure *computations*, with the pure world safely separated and isolated from the impurities of the real world. Or seen from the other side, the pure code being run by the real impure code interacting with the real world (in case `M` is `IO`). Which is what computer programs *must* do, after all.

---

Your `removeItem` is wrong. You should pick and remove items positionally, i.e. by index, not by value; and in any case not remove more than one item after having picked *one* item from the list.

The `y` in `y <- rand 0 (length l)` is indeed an index. Treat it as such. Rename it to `i`, too, as a simple mnemonic.

Comment: I get error on the code above : Couldn't match type `a' with `Int'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          shuffleList :: forall a. [a] -> IO [a]...

Comment: you need to change the signature to `shuffleList :: [Int] -> IO [Int]`. but that's the wrong fix. Your *`removeItem`* is the problem. You should pick and remove items positionally, not by value.